# Access VBA SQL Query for partial words?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to search for partial word(s) and it seems to only return results with the searched word in the beginning.

Example, there's a project called "Test Name" and "Test Name1". And if I search "test name" or "test", I'll return the correct results (both of them). But if I serach for "name", neither is returned.

What am I doing wrong?

```
sqlMiddle = ""
sqlEnd = ";"
sqlProjectName = "tbl_test.projectName "


If Me.tb_ProjectName <> "" Then
    If variationNumber = 0 Then
        sqlProjectName = " WHERE " & sqlProjectName & " LIKE "
    Else
        sqlProjectName = " AND " & sqlProjectName & " LIKE "
    End If
    sqlProjectName = sqlProjectName & """" & SafeSQL(Me.tb_ProjectName) & "*"""
    sqlMiddle = sqlMiddle & sqlProjectName
    variationNumber = variationNumber + 1
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing an * from your last like, it should read:

```
 """*" & SafeSQL(Me.tb_ProjectName) & "*"""
```